# Pull to refresh jumps while dragging

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I've used this tutorial to implement pull to refresh in tableview
https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-pull-to-refresh-to-a-table-view-or-collection-view

Cells have dynamic height in my table.

When I pull to refresh and drag down (before I can release), table jumps. I've been reading various solutions and tried few but I couldn't fix this issue. Is there any definite solution for this problem?

I've tried following solutions:

1) This one doesn't work at all

```
var cellHeights: [IndexPath : CGFloat] = [:]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.size.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return cellHeights[indexPath] ?? 70.0
}
```

2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417756/12114641

This solution seems to work however table jumps when dragging is released, it should be smooth instead of jump.

3) Following also doesn't work

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: What did you already try, what exactly didn't work? And please share a [example].

Comment: I've updated question with few solutions I've tried.

Comment: @koen Was Raymond's code + context enough to figure out what's going on?

Comment: @koen FWIW, Instagram's app has the same problem, suggesting to me that this is probably a hard bug to solve (on the assumption that they have a bunch of devs on their app team).